# IntelliJ Pycharm plugin: move a variable into a class

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, plugins, pycharm, refactoring

I need to refactor a standalone variable to be part of a class... but I can't find the right refactor option in Pycharm's plugin for IntelliJ. It exists? How can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regrettably, no.

Please vote for this feature request in order to increase its priority https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41891.